# Correct Use of Oracle Type Member Functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I have created user-defined types. It has member functions. Almost all use same package function `report_pkg.get_data`. And I do some other stuff.

```
create or replace type report_type is object
 (
  globalvar1 number(15),
  globalvar2 varchar2(8),
  member function getA return varchar2,
  member function getB return varchar2,
  member function getC return varchar2,
  member function getD return varchar2
 )
```

In member function, I use the same function.

```
member function getA return varchar2 is
    rc tb_example%rowtype;
 begin
    rc := report_pkg.get_data(globalvar1 , globalvar2);
    **Other stuff**
    return rc.column1;
 end;


member function getB return varchar2 is
    rc tb_example%rowtype;
 begin
    rc := report_pkg.get_data(globalvar1 , globalvar2);
    **Other stuff**
    return rc.column2;
 end;

member function getC return varchar2 is
    rc tb_example%rowtype;
 begin
    rc := report_pkg.get_data(globalvar1 , globalvar2);
    **Other stuff**
    return rc.column3;
 end;

member function getD return varchar2 is
    rc tb_example%rowtype;
 begin
    rc := report_pkg.get_data(globalvar1 , globalvar2);
    **Other stuff**
    return rc.column4;
 end;
```

When I run the below code in a loop;

```
report_tab := report_type(globalvar1, globalvar2);
insert into tb_report(columna, columnb, columnc, columnd)
values (report_tab.getA, report_tab.getB, report_tab.getC, report_tab.getD);
```

After all i run `report_pkg.get_data` for each member function. It brings performance issues out. How can i improve the performance and what is the correct use of user defined type member functions?

Thank you.

Comment: One step to improve insert is to use `Append` hint if there is not more of other than insert DML operations. Rest you can try to tune your query which is used in ` report_pkg.get_data` pkg to get data.